# Different font size for diffrent screen densities

Tags: android

I am having a trouble with text size

I am using the sp unit

hdpi and mdpi the font looks great and readable

on x & xxhdpi the font is too small

I tried to put a larger font for the later 2 in values-large , values-xhdpi , values-sw320dp

what happens is either the new sizes is applied to all screens or to none but never to the screens I want

if anyone knows where to put the dimens for this two screen size I'd appreciate it or even another way to handle this font behavior

and thanks in advance

Comment: use the proper `/res/values-XY` to put your `dimens.xml` files.

Comment: I did that the issue is sw-400 for example apply to none sw 350 apply to all screens including hdpi and mdpi

Answer (score 0):

You can create different layouts and put them into different folder.

```
layout-small
layout-normal
layout-large
layout-xlarge
```

In that layouts you can put different text sizes according to the screen size.

Comment: but adding the layout 4 times to change the font seems redundant and not a good practice I just can;t figure out why the values fol ignores meder

Answer (score 0):

you can use dp instead of sp .. its the density pixel.. it will keep the ratio same for all the screen..

Or you can add this line to ur textview

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
```

It will automatically adjust the text size according to the screen size.. depending on the line u added..

Comment: `dp` is not used for text size, we use `dp` instead `px` for dimension size and `sp` for text size. your answer is wrong

Comment: u can try it for urself if it works or not.. i have myself used it in many of my projects and its works just fine.. :) peace..

Comment: @AkshaySharma `sp` for text size. read the docs. I post the link if required.

Comment: Read Best practices @ http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. you should prefer the `sp` (scale-independent pixel) to define text sizes. The sp scale factor depends on a user setting and the system scales the size the same as it does for dp. Still the first part  of your anwer is wrong

Comment: Yes google recommends using sp for font but if the user leaves the font for the mobile so small the font for the application looks bad and for some reason the values seems to ignore font size and i can't find out why the strange behavior